# Please i can not solve these problems? related to updates

Tags: updates, cache

Error while refreshing cache problems

[image]

Comment: Please improve your question. Edit your question to 1) summarize the problem in the header 2) Explain the problem in the body of the question. Prevent problems by preferring to use only trusted and well maintained  PPA's

Answer (score 0):

Searching for apt.kitware.com brings me immediately to a detailed instruction page on how to add this PPA. In point 4, I see you need to install software from them that ensures that their keyring stays up to date as they regularly rotate their keys. Your message happens to indicate that the key is not correct, and thus Ubuntu refuses to work with the PPA. Make sure you update the key and keep it updated as per the instructions of the repository.